# OutOfBoundException: Scanner.nextLine() after System.out.println()

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

**SOLUTION** [Scanner is skipping nextLine() after using next(), nextInt() or other nextFoo() methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13102045/skipping-nextline-after-using-next-nextint-or-other-nextfoo-methods)

First the code:
This part works fine: (`pr(String s) <==> System.out.println(s)`)

```
pr("Stage:");
                String stage = sc.next();
                Stage st;
                try{
                    st = Stage.valueOf(stage);
                }
                catch(IllegalArgumentException e){
                    inv();//Println "Invalid Input!"
                    break;
                }
```

end then:

```
pr("End:");
            String en = sc.nextLine();
            LocalDateTime end;
            try
            {
                int d = Integer.parseInt(en.substring(0,2));
                int m = Integer.parseInt(en.substring(3, 5));
                int h = Integer.parseInt(en.substring(7, 9));
                int min = Integer.parseInt(en.substring(10));
                 end = LocalDateTime.of(year, m, d, h, min);
            }
            catch ( NumberFormatException f)
            {
                inv();//Prints Invalid Input!
                break;
            }
```

I get an

```
java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 2
at java.lang.String.substring(Unknown Source)
```

When debugging the scanner is always skipping the "End" input.

**EDIT** 
en is "" but the input seems to be an infinite loop 
(e.g: 12.11. 13:14 \n \n \n ...)
Therefore I cant save my input in en

**EDIT2** Input is always "MM.dd. HH:mm" else print`"Invalid Input"`

How do I get rid of this problem? Is it caused by println?

Comment: Print the value of the `en` String , it is probably shorter than 3 characters .

Comment: Actually the length of `en` would have to be at least 11 for the code _not_ to break. The format would have to be something like `\d{2}.\d{2}..\d{2}.\d+`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is: nextInt() ignores the "\n" character, therefore nextline() reads the rest of the line "\n".

Details: [Scanner is skipping nextLine() after using next(), nextInt() or other nextFoo() methods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13102045/skipping-nextline-after-using-next-nextint-or-other-nextfoo-methods)